# Automatically create new user in Alfresco

Tags: automation, alfresco

I'm trying to automatize the creation/clonation of new servers.

One of the steps I need to implement for this task is the creation of new users in a common Alfresco server.

I can do it manually, but as I managed to automatize all the remaining steps I wonder if there's a way to fully automatize this user creation.

I've searched in Alfresco comunity and found an [old post](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/181295-create-user-script) with recommendations on how not to do it (E.G: updating the database tables), and some broken references to other web services, but nothing useful.

Comment: Put all your users in something like an LDAP directory, and have the server sync users with LDAP?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your expected degree of automation.
Can you please give some insight in what you intend to automate?
If you just want to create users, groups you should go for ldap synchronisation.
Another approach would be to use the csv upload webscript to create users but this is only working for new users and not for groups.
If you're looking for more automation inside Alfresco I would recommend you write your own Alfresco Repository Javascript(s) and make these available by exposing them as a webscript to be called e.g. from curl command.

If you don't want to hassle with Alfresco internals you may take a look into [alfresco-shell-tools](https://github.com/ecm4u/alfresco-shell-tools). Since the shell-tools use some private methods from share UI due to missing alternatives share and search commands may not work in newer Alfresco versions.

Comment: Just creating new users, not groups.

Comment: The [alfresco-shell-tools](https://github.com/ecm4u/alfresco-shell-tools) look really nice!

Answer (score 0):

There is a webscript to create a user. It can be invoked via any Rest API tool like cURL or Postman. POST /alfresco/service/api/people this is the one.